# Who is responsible for creating the window under the hook when using storyboards

Tags: ios

if we are using storyboards to deliver the interface setting in out ios app, then the `AppDelegate.m` will be quite clean and the only thing we are caring about is making our logic code enter at the `viewDidLoad()` function in the viewController which we hooked with a storyboard.

And there is a way that wildly used when we choose not to load the storyboard and make our `window` ourself at `Application didFinishLanchingWithOption` method of `AppDelegate.m` like this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

the document says there should be a `window` and a `rootViewController` for our app to present stuff on the screen.

But if we are using the storyboard, who did this stuff for us? I mean things like creating the window and assign the rootViewController?

And can we choose what kind of rootViewController when using storyboard?

And once a rootViewController is assigned, can we choose to replace that?

Mostly I am asking how did all the stuff organized under hook

Comment: Not sure where exactly that lies, but probably in `UIApplication`. You can use any view controller as your root view controller, you just need to select the one you want in your storyboard. And yes, you could change the root view controller, but in most cases you shouldn't need to.

Comment: Hi @jcaron thanks for reply, after inspecting the mainStoryBoard, I could find the ViewController of the first view is left blank, and there is a `UINavigationController` which is left gray, and how can I know which is the rootViewController by inspecting the storyboard? is there an attribute to indict that? Or I just take the first view and its controller as the `rootViewController` for granted?

Comment: @armnotstrong - Do you want to choose which Storyboard (or which VC from the Storyboard) to load? Or do you want to "ignore" the Storyboard entirely?